# override build number in Hudson

Tags: svn, build-process, hudson, build-automation

How can I override Hudson build number? It sounds like an easy question, but in fact it is not.

Main main goal is to have the SVN revision number as the build number. So I set the env. var. with appropriate plug in and i have:

`BUILD_NUMBER = ${SVN_REVISION}.${BUILD_ID}`
`BUILD_TAG = ${JOB_NAME}.${BUILD_NUMBER}`
`BUILD_NUMBER = ${JOB_URL}.${BUILD_NUMBER}`

and in Hudson log the BUILD_NUMBER is actully overridden:

> BUILD_NUMBER = 32.2010-11-19_14-10-48
>
> BUILD_TAG = hudson-FF.Course Management-32.2010-11-19_14-10-48
>
> BUILD_URL = http://dot-servers:8080/job/FF.Course%20Management/32.2010-11-19_14-10-48

but Hudson still uses its own number and claims that the build number is, let's say, 70 and I wanted it to be 32 (as in the above example).

Comment: Ug. This sounds like it's asking for trouble. It's fine to use the svn revision as a build id that's included in your build. But asking Hudson's build number to advance in lock-step with Subversion can result in problems, e.g. manual builds do not have a unique build number. Why does it matter what Hudson's build number is?

Comment: 1) I understand the uniqueness of the builds is important, that is why I used the ${BUILD_ID} in the ${BUILD_NUMBER}. I was hoping this will resolve the uniqueness issue

Comment: 2) Why I need this? Well, when I have my DLL which is versioned 1.2.3.${SVN_REVISION} I would like to easily reflect this version with Hudson build. Without this reflection I need browse the build list to look for the particular build. Or other scenario: my developers tend to say "I've implemented it in ${SVN_REVISION}" rather than "I've implemented it in ${HUDSON_BUILD_NUMBER}". So, to summarise - this is just a matter of having a way to easily find an interested build, both when looking at the file version and Hudson build list.

Comment: Note: workaround for the bug in the Jenkins "build-name-setter" plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13347?focusedCommentId=165147&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-165147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is not possible to set the build number after the build has started.
2. The build number needs to be numerical.
3. Build numbers need to be unique.

There is a plugin to set the [next build number](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Next+Build+Number+Plugin) of a job. But this is not the functionality you are looking for, since the job is already started. You should have a look at the [fingerprint feature](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Fingerprint) from Hudson. Another nice plugin, that might help you is the [description setter plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Description+Setter+Plugin). Have a look at [this issue](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4930) to get a better understanding about build numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, just change the version number in jobs/project/nexBuildNumber, and then got Manage Hudson tab, and click on 'Reload Configuration from Disk', then it will load the new overridden build number.

Answer (score 0):

When you say Hudson uses its own number, do you mean on the left sidebar?

If so, it is probably because by the time you set it (which I am guessing is through the build > execute shell script), the number has already been used to create the build itself, and therefore it uses 70 instead of 32.

However, since you change the number in the Execute shell script, anything that uses the build number *after* that should use 32.

Comment: Yes, I mean the left sidebar. And my main question is to: how to change that number on the lefst sidebar?

Comment: As far as I know, since that number is created and used before your build knows anything about the SVN REVISION number, I doubt you can change that. However, the file that contains that number is `$HUDSON_HOME/jobs/<projectname>/nextBuildNumber`.

You could try changing the value in the file before starting your next build. Let me know if it works

Comment: In addition, If you have two build steps, you need to set the build number for both steps.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my mind. Instead of changing the Hudson's internal build number I use it to version my binaries. So now I have a binary with such versioning:

`1.2.${SVN_REVISION}.${BUILD_NUMBER}`

and combining it with the Description Setter plugin I can reflect each number everywhere.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: IMHO, it would be good form to upvote (or accept) @Peter's answer since you've decided to use a plugin that he recommended. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Team City CI, which is similar enough to Hudson.

Set **-DSVN_REVISION=123 -DBUILD_NUMBER=456** in your command line parameters to run Maven with. This should override those values.

In Team City I use the Maven BuildNumber Plugin with **-DscmBranch=/releases/2.0.0 -DbuildNUmber=233** to build our releases since the plugin only supports /tags, /branches, and /trunk folder names, but we have a /releases folder. This overrides the values from the scm plugin.