# How to manage product version in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a job to build product A of version 1.2.0.xyz where xyz is build number. In the job we can't configure such version in Jenkins. We want this version info to be auto incrimented for every build and also be visible in current running/completed jobs. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
Sanketh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins/Hudson - accessing the current build number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167650/jenkins-hudson-accessing-the-current-build-number)

Answer (score 0):

If this is not about accessing the current build number, then it sounds like the accepted answer in [override build number in Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226051/override-build-number-in-hudson) would cover this - use the Next Build Number plugin, right?